# Highlighting/Underline name(s) of specific author(s) in HTML publication list

Tags: html, html-lists, bibtex

I am exporting a .bibtex file to HTML code to upload to my website. It creates a list of journal publications. I wanted to be able to highlight/underline the name(s) of specific author(s) in HTML journal citation. How can I do this?

Thanks

```
<p class="infolinks">
\begin{author}\format[AuthorFirstAbbrLastCommas,HTMLChars]{\author}\end{author}\begin{title},
<I><B>\format[Replace("``,\""),Replace("'',\""),HTMLChars,RemoveBrackets]{\title}</B></I>\end{title}\begin{howpublished},
\format[HTMLChars]{\howpublished}\end{howpublished}\begin{primaryclass}
[\primaryclass]\end{primaryclass}\begin{journal},
\format[HTMLChars]{\journal}\end{journal}\begin{booktitle},
\format[HTMLChars]{\booktitle}\end{booktitle}\begin{editor}, 
\format[AuthorFirstAbbrLastCommas,HTMLChars]{\editor} (eds.)\end{editor}\begin{series}, 
\format[HTMLChars]{\series}\end{series}\begin{publisher}, 
\format[HTMLChars]{\publisher}\end{publisher}\begin{institution},
\format[HTMLChars]{\institution}\end{institution}\begin{school}, 
\format[HTMLChars]{\school}\end{school}\begin{address}, 
\format[HTMLChars]{\address}\end{address}\begin{volume}, 
Volume \volume\end{volume}\begin{number}, 
Number \format[FormatPagesForHTML]{\number}\end{number}\begin{pages}, 
pp. \format[FormatPagesForHTML]{\pages}\end{pages}\begin{year},
\end{year}\begin{month&&month} 
\format[HTMLChars]{\month}\end{month&&month}\begin{year}
\year\end{year}\begin{note},
\note\end{note}\begin{doi} 
[<a href="\format[DOICheck]{\doi}" target="_blank">DOI</a>]\end{doi}
\begin{url} 
<a href="\format{\url}">\url</a>\end{url}

\begin{eprint}[<a href="http://arxiv.org/pdf/\format{\eprint}">PDF</a>]\end{eprint}
\begin{pdf}[<a href="pubfiles/\format{\pdf}">PDF</a>]\end{pdf}
\begin{review}[<a href="javascript:toggleInfo('\format{\bibtexkey}','review')">Review</a>]\end{review}
[<a href="javascript:toggleInfo('\format{\bibtexkey}','bibtex')">BibTeX</a>]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a 'u' tag around the text that you want underlined.
Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/L476uonz/

```
<p>This is an <u>underlined</u> word</p>
```

Or use css inline or by selecting the elements/classes you want to target and applying 'text-decoration: underline;' like this: https://jsfiddle.net/L476uonz/

```
<p style='text-decoration: underline'>Underlined text</p>
```